# How to cast Complex to double

Tags: c#, casting, complex-numbers

I have the following expression:

```
Math.Exp(Complex.ImaginaryOne * new Complex(k0 * X, 0.0))
```

ReSharper caught an error "argument Numeric.Complex isn't assignable to type double". What is the best way to cast this? Is C# has a build-in method or I nave to write some algebra in code to do it?

I didn't find anything useful in google, most questions are about cast from double to Complex.

k0 and X is double.

UPDATE:

Thanks to @GrantWinney for

```
var result = Complex.Exp(Complex.ImaginaryOne * new Complex(k0 * X, 0.0));
```

The whole function is

```
double Psi = A1 * Complex.Exp(Complex.ImaginaryOne * new Complex(k0 * X, 0.0)) + B1 * Complex.Exp((-Complex.ImaginaryOne) * new Complex(k0 * X, 0.0));
```

Psi must be use as y-axis coordinate. Good question from @pmcoltrane. I think I need real part. Is anyone knows am I right? I didn't draw complex graphs before.

A1 and B1 is Complex.

Comment: From System.Numeric.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Complex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has its own methods that mirror many of those available in the `Math` class.

```
Complex result = Complex.Exp(Complex.ImaginaryOne * new Complex(k0 * X, 0.0));
```

As for converting it to a `double`, there are two portions to consider... the "real" value and "imaginary" value. Both are available as `double` values, accessible via properties:

```
double realPart = result.Real;
double imaginaryPart = result.Imaginary;
```

Comment: Just no way! I'm idiot, why don't search for him. One problem is solved. But eventually must be double. I will make update. Thanks

Comment: Whenever you eventually need to convert to double, you'll probably find that you need either the real part or the magnitude. Both of those are `double` properties on the `Complex` object.

Comment: Yes, I know about this properties, it looks the question is about complex graphs now. Need to google.

Comment: Yes,I found it too. Actually I will get two graphs: one is `X `and `Psi.Real`, another is `X` and `Psi.Imaginary`. Good I even understand physical sense of Imaginary graph. Thanks to all.